# Detailed calculations for DIY SSR (solid state relay) circuit

Tags: resistance, opto-isolator, solid-state-relay, triac, diy

I just want to understand the calculations for a DIY SSR project.

I do know the components required but I don't know how to calculate resistance values for this circuit. Also, what is the output of optocoupler (optotriac) to trigger the triac gate?
What is the gate value for NPN transistor?
Can I replace snubber circuit for a simple varistor (MOV)?

My input voltage is 5 V DC.
Mains is 230 V AC.

I want to use a 40A triac for switching 10A load (higher value just for safety and power dissipation).

[image]

Comment: TR1 is a current source for the optocoupler LED. R2 = Vbe/I_LED. Vbe = 0.6 so for say 10 mA LED current R2 = 0.6 / 0.01A = 60 Ohm. || OptoTRIAC output is either off or on for AC.